# ImportError: cannot import name 'NavigateThroughPoses' from 'nav2_msgs.action'

Tags: robotics, ros2

I am trying to follow https://github.com/SteveMacenski/nav2_rosdevday_2021/tree/main/nav2_rosdevday_2021

As I run robot_navigator.py, I am getting

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'NavigateThroughPoses' from 'nav2_msgs.action' (/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nav2_msgs/action/__init__.py)
```

The problem is in

```
from nav2_msgs.action import NavigateThroughPoses, NavigateToPose, FollowWaypoints, ComputePathToPose, ComputePathThroughPoses
```

It can not find NavigateThroughPoses and ComputePathThroughPoses (while finding the rest).

When I follow to **init**.py, I see:

```
from nav2_msgs.action._back_up import BackUp  # noqa: F401
from nav2_msgs.action._compute_path_to_pose import ComputePathToPose  # noqa: F401
from nav2_msgs.action._dummy_recovery import DummyRecovery  # noqa: F401
from nav2_msgs.action._follow_path import FollowPath  # noqa: F401
from nav2_msgs.action._follow_waypoints import FollowWaypoints  # noqa: F401
from nav2_msgs.action._navigate_to_pose import NavigateToPose  # noqa: F401
from nav2_msgs.action._spin import Spin  # noqa: F401
from nav2_msgs.action._wait import Wait  # noqa: F401
```

So NavigateThroughPoses and ComputePathThroughPoses are, indeed, not there.

Any idea what is wrong and how to fix it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unable to find them there because they do not exist for ROS2 Foxy and have only been made available from ROS2 Galactic onwards.

[Here](https://navigation.ros.org/migration/Foxy.html) is the page on the ROS2 Navigation documentation that mentions the specific addition of NavigateThroughPoses and ComputePathThroughPoses in ROS2 Galactic.

Would be best to move from Foxy to Galactic and try your code instead of breaking one's head trying to adapt the newer code to run in Foxy (if even possible).

Comment: Thank you. I have installed Galactic, and yes, they are there.

Comment: Glad this was of help. Please accept the answer so that the question can be marked as resolved.